# SQL Replace instance of word with another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search through a table column for: **`<o:p />`** to then replace it to **`</p>`**

I know it to be the REPLACE function but unsure how to correctly format the query.

Comment: Use `REPLACE(ColumnName , '<o:p />' , '</p>')`

Comment: update table set column=REPLACE(column,'<o:p />', '</p>') where condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace values in a column you would do this:

```
update tablename set
columnname = replace(columnname, '<o:p />', '</p>')
WHERE columnname LIKE '%<o:p />%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table 
set column=replace(column,'<o:p />', '</p>') 
where condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok in you use mysql you can use to find  and replace with

```
Select replace(<column name>,'<o:p />','</p>') from <table>
```